# String won't assign to string array

Tags: c++

I'm guessing I've done something really stupid, but the string "elem" in enqueue won't assign to the string array "heap". Is this something to do with the fact that it's a const passed by reference?

```
#include "pqueue-heap.h"
using namespace std;

HeapPQueue::HeapPQueue() {
    heap = new string[1000];
}
HeapPQueue::~HeapPQueue() {
    delete[] heap;

}

string HeapPQueue::peek() const {
    // placeholder so method compiles..
    // replace with your own implementation
    return "";
}

string HeapPQueue::extractMin() {

    // placeholder so method compiles..
    // replace with your own implementation
    return peek();
}

void HeapPQueue::enqueue(const string& elem) {

    logSize++;

    heap[logSize] = elem;
    bubbleUp(logSize);
}

void HeapPQueue::bubbleUp(int i) {
    if (i / 2 == 0) return;
    string insert = heap[i];
    string node = heap[i / 2];
    if (insert >= node) return;

    heap[i] = node;
    heap[i / 2] = insert;
    bubbleUp(i / 2);
}

HeapPQueue *HeapPQueue::merge(HeapPQueue *one, HeapPQueue *two) {
    // placeholder so method compiles..
    // replace with your own implementation
    return new HeapPQueue();
}
```

logSize is protected, here it is mentioned in the pqueue header file;

```
/**
 * File: pqueue.h
 * --------------
 * Defines the interface that all PQueues must implement.  VectorPQueue,
 * HeapPQueue, and BinomialHeapPQueue all subclass PQueue so that they
 * all agree on the same interface.
 */

#ifndef _pqueue_
#define _pqueue_

#include <string>

/**
 * Defines the PQueue container type for strings. The priority queue
 * holds all enqueued strings, but rather than making them accessible
 * in a FIFO manner, extractMin produces the alphabetically smaller strings
 * before the alphabetically larger ones, regardless of insertion order.
 * 
 * The generalization of this would be a templated priority queue, useful
 * in a large number of algorithmic settings (optimization problems, simulations,
 * shortest path problems, network routing, etc.)
 */

class PQueue {
public:

/**
 * Defines a small set of constants that can be used to identify
 * the particular implementation of interest.  They're most vital to
 * the construction of a PQueue using the factory method, as with
 *
 *     PQueue *pq = PQueue::createPQueue(PQueue::BinomialHeap);
 *    
 * Enumerated constants are programmatically easier to manage than
 * type names, and it's easy to internally dispatch on enumerated
 * type constants than it is to on type names.
 */

    enum PQueueType {
        UnsortedVector, LinkedList, Heap, BinomialHeap
    };

/**
 * Convenience function that gives us a string name for the
 * PQueue represented by type.
 */

    static std::string typeToName(PQueueType type);

public:

/**
 * Manages the initialization of the material managed at the PQueue,
 * base class, level.  We assume that all subclasses, regardless of
 * implementation, track their logical size using the logSize
 * parameter held at the PQueue class level.  By doing so, we can
 * rely on a single implementation of the isEmpty() and size() methods
 * that never have to be overridden.  Construction at this level is
 * so obvious that we just inline the implementation.
 */

    PQueue() { logSize = 0; }

/**
 * Disposes of any external resources held at the PQueue level.
 * Nothing, save for an internal int, is managed at the PQueue level,
 * so the destructor is inlined here.
 */

    virtual ~PQueue() {}

    static PQueue *createPQueue(PQueueType type);
    static PQueue *merge(PQueue *one, PQueue *two);

/**
 * Returns the number of elements inside the PQueue.  This
 * method should not be overridden, and subclasses properly
 * maintain the value of logSize so that the implementation
 * provided here is always correct.
 */

    int size() const { return logSize; }

/**
 * Returns true if and only if the PQueue is empty.  Self-explanatory,
 * save for the fact that isEmpty should not be overridden.
 */

    bool isEmpty() const { return size() == 0; }

/**
 * Inserts the provided string into the priority queue as the
 * implementation sees fit.  The virtual keyword, paired with the
 * = 0, is C++ notation stating that no sensible implementation
 * exists at this level, and that concrete subclasses should 
 * provide one.
 */

    virtual void enqueue(const std::string& elem) = 0;

/**
 * Identifies, removes, and returns the lowest-priority element currently
 * in the priority queue.  The behavior is undefined if called against
 * an empty queue. The virtual keyword, paired with the
 * = 0, is C++ notation stating that no sensible implementation
 * exists at this level, and that concrete subclasses should
 * provide one.
 */

    virtual std::string extractMin() = 0;

/**
 * Returns a copy of the lowest-priority item currently within
 * the queue. The virtual keyword, paired with the
 * = 0, is C++ notation stating that no sensible implementation
 * exists at this level, and that concrete subclasses should
 * provide one.
 */

    virtual std::string peek() const = 0;

protected:

/**
 * Maintains a copy of the size of the priority queue, regardless of the
 * subclass's implementation.  Care much be taken to ++ and -- this
 * field (visible to all suclasses because of the protected access modifier)
 * with each call to enqueue and extractMin, and that the logSize is properly
 * updated with each merge.
 */

    int logSize;
};

#endif
```

This is the header file for heappqueue;

```
#ifndef _binary_heap_pqueue_
#define _binary_heap_pqueue_

#include "pqueue.h"
#include <string>

class HeapPQueue : public PQueue {
public:
    HeapPQueue();
    ~HeapPQueue();

    static HeapPQueue *merge(HeapPQueue *one, HeapPQueue *two);

    void enqueue(const std::string& elem);
    std::string extractMin();
    std::string peek() const;

private:

    std::string *heap;
    void bubbleUp(int logSize);
    // provide data methods and helper methods to
    // help realize the binary heap-backed PQueue
};

#endif
```

Here's how the class is enqueued;

```
template <typename Iterable>
static PQueue *buildPQueue(PQueue::PQueueType pqtype, Iterable iter, int size) {
    PQueue *pq = PQueue::createPQueue(pqtype);
    int count = 0;
    foreach (string key in iter) {
        pq->enqueue(key);
        count++;
        if (count == size) break;
    }

    cout << "+ Inserted " << pq->size() << " words." << endl;
    return pq;
}
```

Here's how the type struct is laid out;

```
static const struct {
    PQueue::PQueueType type;
    int reasonableTestSize;
} testParameters[] = {
    { PQueue::UnsortedVector, 10000},
    { PQueue::LinkedList, 10000},
    { PQueue::Heap, INT_MAX},
    { PQueue::BinomialHeap, INT_MAX}
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "won't assign"?

Comment: The program hangs and I get an error on that line heap[logSize] = elem;

Comment: My first guess would be `logSize` >= 1000

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? If so what's the value of `logSize`?

Comment: Definitely array access out-of-bounds problem!

Comment: std::vector<std::string> and push_back would have avoided this problem. If you're confident using std::string why not also use std::vector? These things exist to make programming easier!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The constructor you show doesn't initialize `logSize`. This could well be at least part of the problem.</strike>

Also, `heap` has a fixed size and `enqueue()` doesn't check for overflow.

Comment: logSize is zero, I'm putting it to 1 so that logSize tracks where everything should be for the heap sort...

Comment: @RobbieCooper: Please edit your answer to include all parts of the code that mention `logSize`.

Comment: logSize is initialized in one of the other classes. There's a pQueue file that all of the different implementations in this exercise refer to.

Comment: I've edited it to show the header file and logSize, which is protected. I'll add an expand heap function later, at the moment its hanging on the first try.

Comment: @RobbieCooper: Fair enough. Why don't you also show us the header file where `HeapPQueue` is declared?

Comment: @RobbieCooper: Other than the potential array overflow, I don't see any problems. How many elements are you adding?

Comment: #0 0x9b17bf20 in std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&) ()

Comment: That's the error message. I increased the array initialization to 10k just to check that. It does appear to be hanging on first try.

Comment: @RobbieCooper: The only piece that's missing is how you're instantiating and using your class. Let's see that code.

Comment: I've added it, or parts of it. There's a pqueue test cpp that runs tests on all the implementations (vector backed, heap, binomial heap etc...)

Comment: Oh my god- I just increased the array size to a million and its running and running. NPE and quite a number of people were right in the first place. the test cpp is enqueueing a new number of strings... Sorry !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are **not using slot 0 of heap**. Instead try post incrementing logSize.
Also, there has to be some kind of bounds check before accessing array heap.

```
    void HeapPQueue::enqueue(const string& elem) {
        heap[logSize] = elem;
        bubbleUp(logSize);
        logSize++;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... Could be some problem in call to bubbleUp(logSize); Does it still hang if you comment-out bubbleUp(logSize) and run?

Comment: #0 0x9b17bf20 in std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&) ()
This is the error message...

Comment: Looks like something to do with compiler options? Is your code compiled with FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING option? Pls have a look at http://newartisans.com/2009/10/a-c-gotcha-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: Sorry, the test cpp is adding a new number of strings. I just increased the array size to a million and its running. I have to add the code to exand the array etc for it to work. The graphics window normally shows every 1k words added, which wasnt happening- hence the confusion.